# TFS Isn't recognizing added item VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, controls

I am working with VS2013 and TFS Online.

When I add a new item some time the Source Control doesn't recognize it as added item but the csproj is updated with the new file's path. When a partner get the latest version and try to copile, it says that a file is missed.

When I am checking in I see that some added files can't be included for check in. Sometimes added files doesn't have the plus icon so I can add it with "Add to source control" but sometimes the plus icon is there and I still can't check in the file.

It's happening with png in resources and cs of a Winform

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have the Solution/Project bound to TFS correctly - this is a step you must take to make VS work with TFVC (local and server).

You can usually tell when it is not setup by the icons on the project file in Solution Explorer:

**Not Setup**:

[image: Not bound]

**Setup:**

[image: Bound]

*Notice the padlocks*

To setup the bindings go to **File** > **Source Control** > **Advanced** > **Change Source Control...**

Select the project and/or solution and click **Bind**:

[image]

Once the solution is bound, new projects added to it will also be bound.

Also, if you have set this up in the past and it's not working, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602620/what-tfs-folder-should-the-solution-file-be-bound-to/30607860#30607860) - it shows you how to redo the bindings when the are messed up.