# Problems with TFS when I try obtain the latest version of Control Version

Tags: version-control, tfs

I configure TF version control (TFVC) in my work, TFSCV works fine, but when an user added files or folders into the project and realize check-in, and other user obtains the latest version of the project, every files or folders added by the other user (which makes check-in) isn't integrated to the project.

The files added appear hidden in the source code explorer, to add this files need obtains the latest version of specific file and add manually at project.

I searched a solution for this problem but I not find a solution and I not have idea what is this about.

Comment: Sounds like a binding [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988423/tfs-isnt-recognizing-added-item-vs2013/30989415#30989415) on the project file, or that someone isn't checking in the Project File (csproj, vbproj, etc).

Comment: Thanks, I read the post but my project is linked to the server, and the users (clients) realize check-in directly of Team Explorer into pending changes but even so this problem occurs.

Comment: Are they checking in the project file as part of the changeset? E.g. `File1.cs [add]` and `MyProj.csproj [edit]` .

Comment: I see sometimes that this file not is part of the changeset , this file must be of the changeset ? and other question if the file is not part of the changeset how add this file automatically on every changeset ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is the file that tells the files to appear in source control explorer. I have no reason (other than bindings) why someone wouldn't be checking this file in.

Comment: Thansk, I will make sure when an user realise a check-in, this file be part of part of the changeset.