# Targeting multiple projects in VS2015 with Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a really big project which includes an application and some class libraries.

I want to set everything under source control but it's tracking only one project at a time

[image: source control tracking only one project]

The projects are into different folders, but tracking and saving them individually wouldn't be a problem either.

Comment: Have you checked the binding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602620/what-tfs-folder-should-the-solution-file-be-bound-to/30607860#30607860 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988423/tfs-isnt-recognizing-added-item-vs2013/30989415#30989415

Comment: Which version control are you using? TFVC or Git?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFVC, try to go to "VS\File\Source Control\Advanced\Change Source Control" and click "Bind" button for the untracked projects. The status of the projects is usually "Not Controlled" if they are not bind.

Comment: File -> Source Control is missing. I can still commit and everything with the Team Explorer tab though. Under Tools -> Source Control I have  Microsoft Git Provider, which I am currently using. It is connected remotely to Visual Studio Team Services

Comment: @AlexanderD So you are using Git version control. Can you share your folder structure? And are all the projects added in VSTS?

Comment: Sure, 
`C:\ -> inetpub -> wwwroot -> MyProject -> aspx etc.` 
`C:\ -> MyLibraries -> Library1-2-3.csproj`.
The projects are not in VSTS, that's what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: @AlexanderD Since you are using Git which is different with TFVC, you need to make sure all your projects are placed in your local Git repository folder. Otherwise, the projects outsitde the Git repo folder cannot be detected and tracked.

Comment: May I add individual repos for the projects under `C:\ -> MyLibraries -> Library1-2-3.csproj` which are currently listed in the same solution as my main project?

Comment: You can, but you will need to create individual remote repositories on VSTS for them. And you can still only track the projects under the repository you selected from Source Control Explorer.