# TFS Constant Error Output TF10121: The path '' is not found or not supported. Type or select a different path

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Using TFS in Visual Studio 2013, another Team member made many changes to the solution structure (moving files between projects, new projects, new dtsx files, updating most files, consolidating connection managers).  After getting latest, whenever I open the solution the Output window now pops up and continuously lists the same error:

**TF10121: The path '' is not found or not supported. Type or select a different path.

(this error repeats about once per second)**

There is a similar post here for VS 2013 with similar error, though apparently not with the near constant repetition of the error and no help.

Pinning the Output window helps by at least preventing the constant stream of repeating errors from changing the focus while I work.

No change after reinstalling software.

Closing the solution stops the errors. Unloading all the projects stops the errors, but they resume when reloading.

Opening a file in the soln sometimes temporarily halts the errors.

Opening a local solution is fine, adding the solution to source control causes error to start

Comment: Have you tried redoing the TFS bindings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602620/what-tfs-folder-should-the-solution-file-be-bound-to/30607860#30607860

Comment: Just tried error stopped after re-binding and did not reappear during the session, However, error returned the next time closed and reopened. Just noticed another couple lines interspersed in the errors, not sure if they were there before.

TF10121: The path '' is not found or not supported. Type or select a different path.
The string must have at least one character.
Parameter name: path

Comment: Does the issue occur if you create a new solution and add it into source control?

Comment: Created New Solution, added into Source Control. As soon as checked in, the error starts up.

Comment: Can you try creating a new workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an error with the workspace mappings. It may be that your workspace mapping contains a drive which is no longer available or another issue that breaks the workspace. Possible issues:

- Drive no longer available
- Inaccessible network drive
- Permissions are blocking access to a folder
- Your mapping may require you to run with Elevated Privileges.
- The target mapping may be empty

From the <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Source Control</kbd> and edit the workspace. If editing doesn't solve it, try deleting the workspace completely and creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

We using VS SSIS 2012, in solution folder I have .vssscc file and it has very short config info. I saw two parameters have empty value like ""

"PROJECT_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" = ""
"ORIGINAL_PROJECT_FILE_PATH" = ""

So I changed to 
"PROJECT_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" = "."
"ORIGINAL_PROJECT_FILE_PATH" = "."

And seems removed message.  As you can see I have no explanation. Just tried and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me in Visual Studio 2017 with a solution that contained a python project. One of the python environments was an old environment I deleted before. Once I removed that environment from the project the repeating error stopped.